# Private variable issue in a function environnement

Tags: equation-solving, functions, function-construction, map

I have the following matrix which represents an input from a .txt file. The first column gives the name of the random variable, the second the probability law, the third the parameters related to the law.

```
InputMatrix = {{"Phi", "Lognormal", {30, 2.4}}, {"C", 
"Lognormal", {5, 1}}};
```

in table form:

[image]

I built the following two functions :

```
LogNormalSolver[mat_] :=
  Module[{\[Lambda], \[Zeta]},
      NSolve[{mat[[1]] == Exp[\[Lambda] + \[Zeta]^2/2],
              mat[[2]] == Exp[\[Lambda] + \[Zeta]^2/2]*Sqrt[Exp[\[Zeta]^2] - 1],
      \[Lambda] \[Element] Reals, \[Zeta] > 0}, {\[Lambda], \[Zeta]}]
  ]

getLaw[mat_, i_] :=
  Module[{\[Mu]X, \[Sigma]X},
   Map[
    Which[# == "Lognormal",LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu]X, \ 
         [Sigma]X]/.LogNormalSolver[InputMatrix[[All, 3]][[i]]]] &, 
    mat[[All, 2]]][[i]]
 ]
```

My question is:

why can't the getLaw[] function access the two parameters calculated in the LogNormalSolver[] function and show me the following result ?

```
getLaw[InputMatrix, 1]

out:{LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu]X$15188, \[Sigma]X$15188]}
```

Note that I am a beginner in programming and I may not know all the subtleties with private and public variables etc...

Thank you in advance for the answer

Comment: Please describe what you want to do. It is hard to figure this out from your code alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogNormalSolver` does not know about the local variables in `getLaw`. One solution would be to pass those variables to `LogNormalSolver`, so that it expresses its solution in terms of them

```
LogNormalSolver[mat_, lam_, zeta_] := 
  NSolve[{mat[[1]] == Exp[lam + zeta^2/2], 
    mat[[2]] == Exp[lam + zeta^2/2]*Sqrt[Exp[zeta^2] - 1], 
    lam \[Element] Reals, zeta > 0}, 
    {lam, zeta}
  ];

getLaw[mat_, i_] := 
  Module[{muX, sigX}, 
    Map[Which[# == "Lognormal", 
   LogNormalDistribution[muX, sigX] /. LogNormalSolver[InputMatrix[[All, 3]][[i]], muX, sigX]] &,
   mat[[All, 2]]][[i]]
];

getLaw[InputMatrix, 1]
(* {LogNormalDistribution[3.39801, 0.0798724]} *)
```

Comment: Helped a lot, thanks !